Rounding off decimals in Django not working as expected?
I am using Django version 3.2.16.
In Django I am using below code.
Here for example income__ownership is 2500 and the value of amount_field is 14826.So when  multiplying 14826 by.25 it gives value as 37.715 and  I want the rounded result as 35.72 but Django Round gives result as 36. How to achieve desired result?
amount_annotation = ExpressionWrapper(
    # Use Django's Round function to round the base value to 2 decimal places
    Round(
        F(amount_field) * (Cast(F('income__ownership'), FloatField()) / 10000),
        precision=2,  # Round to 2 decimal places
        output_field=FloatField()
    ) * 100,  # Multiply the rounded value by 100
    output_field=IntegerField()
)


What type is amount_field?

amount_field is of DecimalField type.

what if you cast to a DecimalField()?

If income__ownership is 2500 and amount_field is 14826 value before rounding is 3706.35 , rounding following result is still same and multiplying this by 100 would be 370635. Your example calculations are off in every step,  if income is for example 1 and amount is 250 your code will correctly round 0.025 to 0.03 and subsequently after multiplication to 3 so voting to close following question as non reproducible

I would suggest you another approach and, instead, using the python built-in round method.
In this case, you can make the calculation and then obtain the desired behaviour.
amount_annotation =  F(amount_field) * (Cast(F('income__ownership'), FloatField()) / 10000)


rounded_value = round(amount_annotation , 2)
final_amount_annotation = ExpressionWrapper(
rounded_value * 100,
output_field=IntegerField()
)

You should check, of course, this code because I didn't try it.

Thanks for your reply. I tried your solution but getting the error b'{"message": "Something went wrong: type CombinedExpression doesn't define round method"}'
